# Java Minimal Json how to nest multiple arrays in one object?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to use this library in my java project https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json

Here is how it's used to create objects and arrays.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject().add( "name", "John" ).add( "age", 23 );
// -> { "name": "John", "age", 23 }

JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray().add( "John" ).add( 23 );
// -> [ "John", 23 ]
```

I'm trying to create something like this

```
{"start":1234,"end":4321,"time":1000,"cmds":[["String",123],["String2",0],["String3",99999]]};
```

Here is what I tried it didn't compile

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject().add("start", 1234).add("end", 848383).add("cmds", new JsonArray().add("test").add(1234), new JsonArray().add("test2").add(9594), new JsonArray().add("test6").add("down"));
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

This compiles below compiles fine. But it keeps it all as one Array.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject().add("start", 1234).add("end", 848383).add("time", 1000).add("cmds", new JsonArray().add("test").add(1234).add("test2").add(9594).add("test6").add("down"));
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

```
{"start":1234,"end":848383,"time":1000,"cmds":["test",1234,"test2",9594,"test6","down"]}
```

Comment: Well, you create a single array with 6 elements, so that is pretty normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
new JsonArray().add("test").add(1234)
    .add("test2").add(9594)
    .add("test6").add("down")
```

which creates one array of 6 elements, you should:

```
// new array,
new JsonArray()
    // add a new 2-element array in it,
    .add(new JsonArray().add("test").add(1234))
    // add a new 2-element array in it,
    .add(new JsonArray().add("test2").add(9594))
    // add a new 2-element array in it
    .add(new JsonArray().add("test6").add("down"))
```

Comment: thanks it works.. I have to keep it as multiple arrays.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I don't want to change the format i'm trying to emulate a server for a javascript game. Yeah I could probably change the format on both sides  but your solution is perfect no need for anything else, thanks again.